# Price range facets are always disabled with zero count

Tags: django-oscar

I'm using the default setup by Oscar 2.0 with ElasticSearch 2.4.6, however, the price range data generated by facets are always disabled with zero count, the other data related to the fields (rating and product class) are fine

I've noticed that the output of self.results.facet_counts() is just counting the number of items which has a price and not using the provided query for ranges, however, the quert_facets info under the search_query() looks fine, showing the query ranges required

[self.results.facet_counts() screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKHi.png)

[Search_QuerySet.quert_facets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB9q5.png)

[context output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf46h.png)

```py
# Search facets
OSCAR_SEARCH_FACETS = {
    'fields': OrderedDict([
        ('product_class', {'name': _('Type'), 'field': 'product_class'}),
        ('rating', {'name': _('Rating'), 'field': 'rating'}),
    ]),
    'queries': OrderedDict([
        ('price_range',
         {
             'name': _('Price range'),
             'field': 'price',
             'queries': [
                 # This is a list of (name, query) tuples where the name will
                 # be displayed on the front-end.
                 (_('0 to 20'), '[0 TO 20]'),
                 (_('20 to 40'), '[20 TO 40]'),
                 (_('40 to 60'), '[40 TO 60]'),
                 (_('60+'), '[60 TO *]'),
             ]
         }),
    ]),
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091266/show-price-and-rating-in-facet-search

Comment: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2739

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that it is an issue between Haystack and Elasticsearch, Oscar team is working to replace Haystack with their own search interface with Elastic

Answer (score 1):

Zero count indicates that there are no products indexed in that price range. Try setting the price of the product in the shown range and thereafter rebuild indexes.